# OS X Installation USB not detected in Startup Disk selection

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, startup, bootable-disk

I have a MacBook Pro 8.2. Recently I have download Sierra and Yosemite, and am currently running El Capitan.
[image]

And I created a bootable USB for OS X Yosemite with [DiskMaker X 6](http://diskmakerx.com/), in case Sierra goes wrong.

[image: OSX X and DiskMaker]

But when I try to check the USB, it's not on Startup Disk. I tried the option key on mac boot, but the USB is not there.

[image: USB not detected on Startup Disk]

I'm using SanDisk Cruzer Glide Media, here the USB details.

[image: USB Install Disk on Finder]
[image: USB]
[image: USB Volume]

Comment: does the volume show up when you press alt during boot?

Comment: No. But it works when installing El Capitan (current system). It also works with Linux dist, and Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the last image you posted, the window says "Bootable: No". From the screenshot you posted of the files on the USB, this doesn't look like a standard bootable OS X USB. For Yosemite, you could try using Terminal (I'm not sure how Terminal would handle the periods and dashes in your USB's name, so here are the instructions if your USB is named Untitled):

Note that this process automatically erases and formats the USB before moving the files (it normally will confirm this with you), but I like to erase it myself before I do this as a precaution.

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app
```

After the process finishes, I believe the USB is named "Install OS X Yosemite"

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Comment: I did with CLI process using createinstallmedia and the output is the same as DiskMaker did. Not work.

Answer (score 1):

[In order to boot from an external disk it must have a GUID Partition Map](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202796). If your USB disk is not formatted with that you will need to reformat it accordingly.

1. Go to Disk Utility
2. Select "Erase"
3. Select GUID from the "Scheme" dropdown menu

Comment: I did reformat the USB myself using Disk Utility before DiskMaker X 6 do it again and I let the rest don by it.

Answer (score 0):

Mine does the same thing
Terminal says creating bootable.. and it says yes during the make process but later in get info in disk utility it says no for bootable.

I did all kinds of privacy for the file to open anyway and ownership and no matter it just does not boot or flag as bootable with Any method.
Diskcreator 6 no go
Trans mac no go
Terminal says yes but info later says no bootable.

I have downloaded straight from Apple and unpacked to view cert is updated. 
All 3 of the 2.0 USB sticks installed the same mac oses from Lion to Mojave up until this recert stuff.

Any help on this A1466 EMC2925 Air book would help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You’ve posted this as an answer, which is only for things that directly answer the question asked. If you have a different question, feel free to ask it using the Ask Question button at the top right.